# actionmailer: detect what method is called or what mail is send, how?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, layout, conditional-statements, actionmailer

Im using methods to send mails with a "email" layout /app/layouts/email.html.haml

is there a way in Actionmailer to determine from what method a mail is generated from inside the layout?

I need to do some conditional remove of stuff from this layout file based on the method that is called == wich email is send.

Seems like an easy thing but could not find any information on how to to this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably dig through the backtrace, but that's ugly.

Why not tweak your mail method to accept an option such as `:hide_stuff => true` and if that's set, don't show it, otherwise do?  Then, in your method you don't want that stuff to be seen set that option when you call the Mailer method.

Also, `:hide_stuff` is a horrible option name.

Comment: I made a variable in the mailer method and check this in my view, ideal solution to show/hide certain content in the mails!